# Find duplicate rows in 2 fields?

Tags: sql

Can you teach me how to find duplicate or same values in different rows?

```
SELECT * FROM `geoname`
```

Now I need to compare these rows for duplicates:

```
WHERE `feature code` = 'ADM1'

WHERE `feature code` = 'ADM2'
```

UPDATE.

Column NAME contains names that can be duplicates. I wanna find ones?

Comment: What version of SQL are you using?

Comment: PHPMyadmin SQL Apache

Comment: Did you try running my query?

Comment: It outputs the amount of adm1s and adm2. I wanna see which ADM1 name has same value as ADM2 name?

Comment: So you want to see rows that have one row `feature code = ADM1` and one row `feature code = ADM2` and both have the same `NAME`?

Answer (score 2):

To get a count of the occurrences of these two feature codes you can try conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN `feature code` = 'ADM1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS adm1count,
       SUM(CASE WHEN `feature code` = 'ADM2' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS adm2count
FROM yourTable
```

**Update:** If you want to find out which names occur in duplicate then you can try:

```
SELECT NAME
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY NAME
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Comment: Thanks buddy I wanna see which rows with these statements have same name value? if `feature code` = 'ADM1' name == `feature code` = 'ADM2' name sort of speaking

Comment: There is no "sort of" here.  Update your question with the desired output you want.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT geo.*,count(*) as Duplicate_Count
   FROM dbo.geoname AS geo
   having count(*) > 1
   group by geo.*
WHERE `feature code` = 'ADM1' OR `feature code` = 'ADM2'

This Query will return record with its duplicate count,how many times duplication occurred.
```